# How to set up Powershell where-object for filtering EventLog

Tags: windows, powershell, event-log, powershell-3.0

In interactive mode, this works:

```
Get-Eventlog -log application -after ((get-date).addMinutes(-360)) -EntryType Error
```

Now I want to filter out certain messages, the following didn't filter the desired word:

```
Get-Eventlog -log application -after ((get-date).addMinutes(-360)) -EntryType Error | where-object  {$_.$Message -notlike "*Monitis*"}
```

Also, how do I put in multiple conditions on the where-object?

In my script, I'm getting errors on the -and statement:

```
$getEventLog = Get-Eventlog -log application -after ((get-date).addMinutes($minutes*-1)) -EntryType Error 
# list of events to exclude 
$getEventLogFiltered = $getEventLog | where-object {$_.Message -notlike "Monitis*" 
                                       -and $_.Message -notlike "*MQQueueDepthMonitor.exe*"
                                       }
$tableFragment = $getEventLogFiltered | ConvertTo-Html -fragment
```

Error:

```
-and : The term '-and' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\scripts\EventLogExtract2.ps1:24 char:40
+                                        -and $_.Message -notlike "*MQQueueDepthMo ...
+                                        ~~~~
```

Comment: Today, the first part seems to be working (the -notlike). Maybe I had some other timing issue or problem with the -after clause when I ran it yesterday.

Comment: Apparently, you cannot put a line break between each -and?  It seems to work if I put all my and statements on one line.  But this makes the code very hard to read/maintain.  I might eventually have 10 -and statements.  Perhaps I should just use consecutive pipes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your 2nd code snippet remove the dollar sign right before "Message".  Reads like the following.  If you're using PowerShell ISE, you'll see that "Message" should be in black instead of red.

```
Get-Eventlog -log application -after ((get-date).addMinutes(-360)) -EntryType Error | where-object  {$_.Message -notlike "*Monitis*"}
```

For the 3rd code snippet, I placed a [grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) before starting a newline in the Where-Object filter.  This tells PowerShell you're continuing a line instead of beginning a new one.  Also, in PowerShell ISE, the comparison operators (-and & -notlike) turn from blue and black to grey.

```
$getEventLog = Get-Eventlog -log application -after ((get-date).addMinutes($minutes*-1)) -EntryType Error 
# list of events to exclude 
$getEventLogFiltered = $getEventLog | where-object {$_.Message -notlike "Monitis*" `
                                       -and $_.Message -notlike "*MQQueueDepthMonitor.exe*"
                                       }
$tableFragment = $getEventLogFiltered | ConvertTo-Html -fragment
```

Comment: Gee Whiz - haven't seen a language in years that needed a continuation character!  Ah, I see the extra $ sign now, duh...  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Date simplification:
`((get-date).addMinutes($minutes*-1))` has the same output of
 `((get-date).addMinutes(-1))`
and the same output of
`(get-date).addMinutes(-1)`

Also I find `addDays(-1)` to be more useful.

Comment: Nice comment but should not posted as an answer

Comment: "You must have 50 reputation to comment" I think was my reasoning to put this as an answer -- I suppose I could have waited.